# Flickering In VDB Animation?

Tags: rendering, animation, smoke-simulation

I'm getting this very odd flickering in my VDB Simulation. I originally thought this was because of the denoiser. but upon further testing it is still flickering without the denoiser. I've tried cranking up all the light paths, increasing samples to 4096, but still no change.

The Flickering is right in the middle where the red flame is.

reposting this with better video evidence.

[VDB Simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8daAA.jpg)

Comment: Well, if it's not from the denoiser what I would have suspected - how many bounces have you set for _Transparency_ under _Light Paths_? Usually a value that's too low will result in dark flickering, not bright... but it won't hurt to check it ;)

Comment: I've tried bumping all the light paths to over 100 and the issue still persist

Comment: For the smoke only the _Transparency_ bounces are important, but as I said, that's usually causing dark flickering, not your effect. Without a file it's hard to tell. Apart from cranking up the samples, have you also disabled denoising or just increased the samples? And if it's flickering where the flame is... is it maybe just a very noisy flame that's flickering?